# Integrating WPF application with WinForm application

Tags: c#, wpf, vb.net, winforms, migration

I have an winForms application fully written in VB.NET. I have to start importing this application into WPF written C#. For the starting, I want to do this only for one module of the application. Is there any way I can pass VB.NET objects to a C# code, call a WPF application from a WinForms application and vice-versa ?

How should I approach this problem? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: There is information about integration in this article http://stackoverflow.com/questions/694597/migration-from-winforms-to-wpf ElementHost and WindowsFormsHost allow WPF to use Winforms and vice-versa

Answer (score 5):

There is **no easy way** to migrate winform applications to Wpf.

You should carefully consider the reasons why would you like to do it and the effort it will take vs the profit.

that being said you can start by hosting your winform by a wpf application using [WindowsFormHost](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742875.aspx) then you can start by rewriting your controls one at a time and using [ElementHost](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.integration.elementhost.aspx) to host them in the winform.

Since you would like your application to be robust and use `MVVM` I personally think that it will take too much effort to migrate and it will be more reasonable to rewrite the application using already existing modules(logic not ui modules)

Regarding using Vb.net object in c# it can be done easily because they are both managed languages and are being compiled to [CIL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Intermediate_Language):

> During compilation of CLI programming languages, the source code is
>   translated into CIL code rather than platform or processor-specific
>   object code. CIL is a CPU- and platform-independent instruction set
>   that can be executed in any environment supporting the Common Language
>   Infrastructure, such as the .NET runtime on Windows

Answer (score 0):

Yes u can call wpf application in windows and vice-versa.For that u have to configure in .config file

In Through ElementHost u can access the controls

Comment: What kind of configurations are we talking about here?